# jQuery ajax not connect web service .net (asmx)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

i connect javascript ajax to webservice asmx but not work.
i test connect from aspx to webservice it work.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btnCallService').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://xxxxxxxx/ws/webservice.asmx/HelloWorld',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#lblData').html(JSON.stringify(response));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btnCallService" value="GetEmployeeDetail" />
  <label id="lblData"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

after click button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsSF2.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment the below line in your .asmx & it will working.

```
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Comment: not work. error show : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:22759/test.asmx?op=HelloWorld. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your global.asax file and call this method in "Application_BeginRequest"

```
static void EnableCrossDomain()
        {
            string origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin)) return;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            string method = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
            string headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers))
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 204;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry it not work. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o007aiu631j4c4m/AABxNUsz6bTmkEtPbiKj8xAGa?dl=0